# Reading Bytes from Mp3

Tags: c#

I'm using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6826/C-Windows-Media-Format-SDK-Translation) library to read bytes from an mp3:

```
List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
try
{
    using (WmaStream str = new WmaStream(mp3File, new WaveFormat(RATE, 8, 1)))
    {
        bytes.Capacity = (int)str.Length * 2;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[str.SampleSize * 2];

        int read;
        while ((read = str.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
            {
                bytes.Add(buffer[i]);
            }
        }
    }         
}
catch(Exception e)
{

    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
finally
{                
}

return bytes.ToArray();
```

The problem is it sometimes throws `OutOfMemoryException`. I can't tell what exactly is causing the problem but I think it tends to do it especially when reading large mp3 files.

Any idea how to solve this?

Note: interesting ! when i changed the platform target to x64 instead of x86 the problem gone !

Comment: The max size of a List<T> is 2GB -- are you exceeding that?

Comment: no! 105MB is the maximum file i ever tried, however it sometimes give the same exception with small files too 4 or 5 mb

Comment: I just answered another question that may help you understand what's going on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17306484/memorystream-usage-leads-to-out-of-memory-exception/17306712#17306712

Comment: What line does the exception throw on?  What is the stack trace?

Comment: interesting ! when i changed the platform target to x64 instead of x86 the problem gone !

Comment: How big is `str.SampleSize`?

Comment: @Stacker that's because the virtual address space for a 64bit process is much larger.